# Object of type Illuminate\\Http\\Request is not callable, Laravel 8 upload file

Tags: ajax, laravel-8, jquery-file-upload

[Console Log Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOkOK.png)

[UnitController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdAG3.png)

is there someone who can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Request` in the following ways:

```
request('lastName')
$request->lastName
```

In line 65 of the attached image, change `$request()` to `request()`. Simply remove the dollar sign.